# Change the port used by an ASMX service

Tags: c#, .net, iis, port, asmx

I know that SOAP uses default port 80, but it is possible to change webservice SOAP default port (from 80 to 81)?
I am using a .NET webservice hosted in an IIS web server.

Comment: What kind of service? ASMX or WCF?

Comment: most of the services is gets and one set. asmx

Comment: Port has an additional meaning with WSDL related web services. You are referring to a TCP port, as opposed to a `wsdl:service/port` element.

Answer (score 1):

An ASMX service hosted in IIS uses the port configured for the site that it is a part of. You use the Bindings of the site to configure which port or ports, and which address or addresses IIS will listen to. It will then pass the request to the service, which does not actually care which port the request came in on.

Comment: yes, i am binding to port 80. the problem is that the server admin set the port 81 in the router so if i would like to see my webservice i have to put the external ip:81, but when i invoke a service it will go to https (port 443) and return error. in localhost all is working well

Comment: if i bind to port 81 it external ip:81 will not work

Comment: Sounds like the admin should have talked to you before changing network stuff

Comment: i agree, now im stuck